# How do I control volume on a phone using kivy?

Tags: python, android, kivy

So I'm trying to make a program that turns off my phone's notifications for a certain amount of time but I can't figure out how. I'm using kivy for the program and just cannot find anything in the documentation on how to change the volume on a phone.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add relevant code and what approaches you already have tried.

Comment: You probably need to call the android java apis with pyjnius.